# Open Policy Agent - Authorizing READ on a list of data

Tags: http, authorization, open-policy-agent

#### Problem

We've been using OPA to do data authorization of our REST HTTP APIs. We secure our APIs as such

```
allow {
    input.method == "GET"
    glob.match(input.path, ["/"], "/department/DEPARTMENT_ID/employee/")
    some_rule # Where we check that user can list all employee in the particular deparment/DEPARTMENT_ID based on the ACL of department/DEPARTMENT_ID
}
```

As seen above, each `department` has its own ACL we authorize against that for any access to it and its child resources (e.g. employee).

We query this policy via OPA's HTTP API, and we push `department/DEPARTMENT_ID`'s ACL to OPA for it to make a decision. See [OPA docs](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/external-data/#option-4-push-data).

However, there's been a new requirement where we have to make an API that has to list all `employee` that the user has access to.

How could one go about doing this given that the authorization can no longer look at just one ACL? (because multiple `employee` resources will belong in different `department`, each with their own ACL).

#### Potential solution

When listing `employee`, we could send OPA all the ACLs of each of their `department` (i.e. the parent), and have OPA authorize based on that. This could be highly inefficient, but I'm not sure if there's any better way. The size of this is also bounded if we paginate the `employee` listing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I followed entirely, but given that you have `data` looking something like the below:

```json
{
    "departments": {
        "department1": {
            "permissions": {
                "jane": ["read"]
            },
            "employees": {
                "x": {},
                "y": {},
                "z": {}
            }
        },
        "department2": {
            "permissions": {
                "jane": ["read"]
            },
            "employees": {
                "a": {},
                "b": {},
                "c": {}
            }
        },
        "department3": {
            "permissions": {
                "eve": ["read"]
            },
            "employees": {
                "bill": {},
                "bob": {},
                "eve": {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And `input` looking something like this:

```json
{
    "user_id": "jane",
    "method": "GET",
    "department_id": "department1",
    "path": "/department/department1/employee"
}
```

A policy to query for all listable employees for a user might look something like this:

```
package play

import future.keywords.in

allow {
    input.method == "GET"
    glob.match(input.path, ["/"], sprintf("/department/%v/employee", [input.department_id]))
    can_read
}

# Where we check that user can list all employee in the particular deparment/DEPARTMENT_ID based on the ACL of department/DEPARTMENT_ID
can_read {
    "read" in data.departments[input.department_id].permissions[input.user_id]
}

listable_employees[employee] {
    some department in data.departments
    "read" in department.permissions[input.user_id]
    some employee, _ in department.employees
}
```

The `listable_employees` in this case would evaluate to:

```json
[
    "a",
    "b",
    "c",
    "x",
    "y",
    "z"
]
```

Since user `jane` has read access to department1 and department2, but not department3.